# oneall Wordpress plugin - change widget output

Tags: wordpress

I want to implement facebook, twitter and google login on my wordpress blog. I found a great plugin called oneall. It works nicely, I guess (only fb login tested once).
My problem is that I want my own buttons for the login widget. I can change the background images through CSS, but that's not what I want. I want to use an icon font, which I use all across the page. So I need to change the content of the widget to simply 'f', 't' and 'g' and set their font-family.

Here's the part of code that should output the widget code.

```
//Add the Plugin
        $output [] = ' <div class="oneall_social_login_providers" id="oneall_social_login_providers_' . $rand . '"></div>';
        $output [] = ' <script type="text/javascript">';
        $output [] = '  oneall.api.plugins.social_login.build("oneall_social_login_providers_' . $rand . '", {';
        $output [] = '   "providers": ["' . implode ('","', $providers) . '"], ';
        $output [] = '   "callback_uri": (window.location.href + ((window.location.href.split(\'?\')[1] ? \'&amp;\':\'?\') + "oa_social_login_source=' . $source . '")), ';
        $output [] = '   "css_theme_uri": "' . 'http://test.nowillnoskill.net/wp-content/themes/NWNS/design/css/social.css' . '" ';
        $output [] = '  });';
        $output [] = ' </script>';
        $output [] = ' <!-- oneall.com / Social Login for Wordpress / v'.constant('OA_SOCIAL_LOGIN_VERSION').' -->';
        $output [] = '</div>';
```

The javacript is loaded from their server, so I can't change that.

I tried to change it with jQuery (on document ready) like

```
$('#facebook_button').html('f');
```

and I tried it with CSS

```
#facebook_button {content: 'f'}
```

But neither worked. I also tried simply copying the output from the function that should output the code, but that doesn't work either.

You can see my attempts at test.nowillnoskill.net. In the sidebar, there are my icon font buttons at the top (that's what I want) and the buttons with changed background right under them. You can see that the bottom ones are really blurry and ugly.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do it ?
I already asked the authors of the plugin, but they're not responding

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, you already send us a support request for this issue.

You have to add `:before` :

```
#button_facebook:before {
    content: 'f';
}
```

This is however not a very good solution. People that do not have this font installed 
will simply not see the page as intended. The best would be to use custom images.

Comment: Actually "icon fonts" are a perfectly valid way to make icons on your webpage, and surprisingly cross-browser compatible. You just have to include the font in an `@font-face` declaration See [csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/)